# Why the response time is shorter after the same program is excuted many time in Java?

Tags: java, response-time

The response time of a Java program reduces after it is repeated many times. What is the reason for it? Is the following explanation correct?:

> The total execution time includes code generation time + garbage
>   collect time + execution time. After the same program is repeated many
>   times, the code generation time does not appear as a factor.

Can you recommend some references on it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you already have your answer...

Comment: Where did you get your explanation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java is about performance testing and mentions these issues + JIT warmup etc.

Comment: I did a search on the Internet. But I want to verify it and see whether it is accurate. Another question is how many time should the program be repeated?

Comment: The biggest factor is the way that Java code is compiled, and the ability for the compiler to optimise the code when it's run repeatedly. Plenty of information on that to be found using your favourite search engine.

Comment: Look up "just in time compiler".

Comment: Although, keep in mind that this behaviour is technically an _implementation detail_ of modern JVMs, and cannot be relied upon to exist in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Another question is how many time should the program be repeated?

On the HotSpot / OpenJDK the default is 10,000 times see the `-XX:CompileThreshold=` option

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html